# AnithingSlider - How do I change the slides to slide 'non stop'?

Tags: anythingslider

I am rather new to JS and I started playing around with the 'AnythingSlider' JavaScript.

One problem I am facing is that I would like the slides to display in sequence 'non-stop', for example, I would like the slides to constantly move.

I have tried to play around with the 'Times' settings in the .js file, but I am not able to achieve the desired result.

```
    // Times
    delay               : 3000,      // How long between slideshow transitions in AutoPlay mode (in milliseconds)
    resumeDelay         : 15000,     // Resume slideshow after user interaction, only if autoplayLocked is true (in milliseconds).
    animationTime       : 600,       // How long the slideshow transition takes (in milliseconds)
    delayBeforeAnimate  : 0,         // How long to pause slide animation before going to the desired slide (used if you want your "out" FX to show).
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these options ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/3901/)):

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({

    // If true, builds the forwards and backwards buttons
    buildArrows: false,
    // If true, builds a list of anchor links to link to each panel
    buildNavigation: false,
    // If true, builds the start/stop button
    buildStartStop: false,

    // if false, keyboard arrow keys will not work for this slider.
    enableKeyboard: false,

    // If true, the slideshow will start running; replaces "startStopped" option
    autoPlay: true,
    // If true, user changing slides will not stop the slideshow
    autoPlayLocked: true,

    // If true & the slideshow is active, the slideshow will pause on hover
    pauseOnHover: false

});
```

- Note that these options are the only ones that are different from the default setting. I left in ALL of the options in the demo so you can play :)
- And if I totally misunderstood you and you meant to have the slider continuously slide, then please note that there will always be a very brief pause between slides; if that isn't acceptable, then you might need to find another plugin. Sorry =(... Try these additional settings ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/3902/)):

  ```
  delay: 100,
  resumeDelay: 15000,
  animationTime: 3000,
  delayBeforeAnimate: 0
  ```

Comment: Thanks, Originally I was trying the effect with auotPlay: true, & autoPlayLocked: true but was unable to achieve the non-stop effect. Whenever i clicked in some other window or performed some direct movement to a particular slide.. the slider stopped. // Thanks for the answer.